# python. Build exe

Tags: python, python-3.6, cx-freeze, xmldiff

I'm trying to build a project in exe through cx_Freeze.
The project uses the xmldiff library, which does not want to work after assembly.

```
#setup.py
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

__version__ = "0.1"

include_files = []
excludes = ["tkinter"]
packages = ["os", "idna", "requests", "json", "base64", "encodings", 'asyncio', 'xmldiff', 'appdirs']
includes = ['atexit', 'numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format', 'appdirs', 'xmldiff']

setup(
    name = "Project",
    description='Project',
    version=__version__,
    options = {
        "build_exe": {
            'packages': packages,
            'include_files': include_files,
            'excludes': excludes,
            'include_msvcr': True,
            'includes': includes,
        }
    },
    executables = [Executable("designer.py", base="Win32GUI")]
)
```

[image: Error]

What could be the problem?

xmldiff package installed
[image]

Comment: So you are saying that your code is working before using `cx_Freeze`?

Comment: @Eypros, yes, if I run through python.exe

Comment: Do you run the freezing command `python.exe setup.py build` through the same python.exe?

Comment: Have you tried to add `'pkg_resources'` to the `packages` list? And tried to remove the `includes` entries which are already present in `packages`?

Comment: Which GUI library are you using?

Comment: @jpeg, 
1) "Do you run the freezing command python.exe setup.py build through the same python.exe?" - yes. 
2) "Have you tried to add 'pkg_resources' to the packages list?" - yes. 
3) "And tried to remove the includes entries which are already present in packages?" - no. 
4) GUI - wxPython.